How can I send HttpOnly Cookies to the user
I tried all the things I can find on the Internet, but nothing worked.
I did enableCors and cookies parse in Nestjs:
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3001',
    credentials: true,
  });

I also set sameSite to none and secure to false when login:
    response.cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      maxAge: ms(this.configService.get<string>('JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRE')),
      secure: false,
    });

After login, I receive the Set-Cookies from response:
Cookies in the header
Cookies tab
The front-end, I use React Query with Axios:
const useRefresh = () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['refreshToken'],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const response = await AxiosClient.get('/auth/refresh', {
        withCredentials: true
      });
      return response.data;
    }
  });
};

But when I request to endpoint, only Access token is sent with the Cookie
Everything is fine when I use Swagger or Postman

I would tend to think you have a CORS issue with your cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflight_requests_and_credentials

SameSite=None cookies must be set with secure: true and using HTTPS
response.cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: 'none',
  maxAge: ms(this.configService.get<string>('JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRE')),
  secure: false,
});

For more info about how to debug cookie problems, visit this blog post thta I wrote : Debugging cookie problems

I followed your tutorial: set secure to true, ran https server in Nextjs using --experimental-https flag but it just rejected the access_token and didn't add the refresh token into the request. Same with ngrok

seen https://dev.to/elmehdiamlou/efficient-refresh-token-implementation-with-react-query-and-axios-f8d ?
